# Python: Weird error when assigning arg values to variables

Tags: python, argparse

I have a weird error thrown by python when trying to assign values from `argparse` to variables.

My code is:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--hostname', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('--username', default='root', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--password', default='uy4h183D')
    parser.parse_args()
    hostname = args.hostname
    username = args.username
    password = args.password
    file = hostname + '.csv'
    print("The filename is {0}".format(file))
    main()
```

The error is:

```
./4collect.py --hostname bar 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./4collect.py", line 68, in <module>
hostname = args.hostname
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Comment: You never defined a variable called `args`.  Where do you expect it to come from?

Comment: Use `args = parser.parse_args()`

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a special array called args that holds the arguments given? Am I wrong?

Comment: @LeoShatokhin: Yes, you are wrong.

Comment: You may be thinking of `sys.argv`, which is where the command line arguments are accessed within your code.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yes, that's what I was thinking of. Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to assign `args`:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
```